# A simple, backwards-compatible tab navigation example?

Tags: android

I've spent the past 3-4 days looking for clear examples of tab navigation that would work on `Android` versions before 3.0, but every example I've gone through simply doesn't work (causes a crash) on the `AVD emulator`. In some cases these examples are extremely complicated and difficult to reproduce.

I'm reaching out to anyone in the `SO` community who could point me towards a walkthrough for a simple Tab-based navigation system for my App. I'd like it to be backwards-compatible for `Android` versions older than 3.0.

I'd be really grateful if anyone can simply point me towards a tutorial. I am by no means demanding anyone do this, but if someone is feeling particularly charitable the extra attention would be *really* appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try ViewPager? It's backwards-compatible to Android 2.x
[image]

Check out it here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Comment: You know, I've never worked with ViewPagers before, but I'll give them (and your library) a shot. Thanks for the tip!